# React Transition Group can't fire life cycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-transition-group

How to make the life cycle of React Transition Group work?

I have a simple example with 2 components.
The Projects one, which will use the ReactTransitionGroup and the Index Componente, which is the one that I would like to receive the life cycle from ReactTransitionGroup:

```
import React from 'react';
import Index from 'components/views/components/Index';
import TransitionGroup from 'react-addons-transition-group'

class Projects extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='content'>
        <TransitionGroup>
          <Index />
        </TransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And my Index component:

```
class Index extends React.Component {
  componentWillAppear (callback) {
    console.log('will appear');
    callback();
  }

  componentDidAppear () {
    console.log('did appear');
  }

  componentWillEnter (callback) {
    console.log('will enter');
    callback();
  }

  componentDidEnter () {
    console.log('did enter');
  }

  componentWillLeave (callback) {
    console.log('will leave');
    callback();
  }

  componentDidLeave () {
    console.log('did leave');
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='index'>
        <h2>Index Page</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I just need the life cycle dispatchs.

A great article that I found about my problem but I couldn't replicate the results:
https://medium.com/@slapspapayas/reacttransitiongroup-explained-through-failure-629efe364866

**React version**: ^16.2.0

**React Addons Transition Group**: ^15.6.2

Thanks!

Comment: any reason you're using 'react-addons-transition-group' and not [this](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/)?

Comment: I will use GreenSock lib for animation, but I need to use the life cycles of React Transition Group to control the flow (willLeave and willEnter).

Comment: but as @Shirley is saying, why not use the recommended new transition group, they have life cycle hooks through onEvent, you can read the docs and examples https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/

Answer (score 0):

Actually these lifecyles are removed. See the [migration](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/Migration.md)
As from the migration, the child lifecycles are removed. We can pass callback to the Transition component:

```
<Transition
  {...props}
  onEnter={handleEnter}
  onEntering={handleEntering}
  onEntered={handleEntered}
  onExit={handleExit}
  onExiting={handleExiting}
  onExited={handleExited}
/>
```

Comment: Please provide essentials point from link incase link may be broken or content might be removed in future.